# Initialise unique_ptr inside class

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, unique-ptr

I want to initialise the unique pointer inside class after declaration and I tried few ways but unable to resolve the errors..

```
template <typename T>
struct Destroy
{
    void operator()(T *t) const
    {
        t->destroy();
    }
};

class Test
{
    
    std::unique_ptr<IRuntime, Destroy<IRuntime>> runtime;

public:
    Test()
    {
        /*
        the function createIRuntime() return type is *IRuntime.
        I tried using following but all the ways I got error:
        1. runtime = std::make_unique<IRuntime, Destroy<IRuntime>> (createIRuntime());  
        2. runtime = createIRuntime();  
        3. runtime = std::unique_ptr<IRuntime, Destroy<IRuntime>> (createIRuntime());        
               
                 Works fine if I do follow.
                 std::unique_ptr<IRuntime, Destroy<IRuntime>> runtime(createIRuntime());
        */
        
        /* how to initialize the unique pointer here*/
    }
};
```

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly? #3 should work. Also, have you tried `runtime.reset(createIRuntime())` yet? But, since this is inside a constructor, you should use the member initialization list: `Test() : runtime(createIRuntime()) {}`

Comment: I also tried reset but its also giving same error,I can use member initialisation syntax inside the constructor but I also want to know how should I do inside the class member method? And the errors are related to the member function of the pointer.since pointer is not initialise there is not members....

Comment: Terminology nitpick: those are assignments, not initializations. The distinction is very important in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cpp
runtime = std::make_unique<IRuntime, Destroy<IRuntime>> (createIRuntime());
```

Presumably `IRuntime` is an abstract class, which can't be constructed directly.

But even if it could be constructed as-is, only the 1st template parameter specifies the type to create. The 2nd and subsequent template parameters specify the types of parameters for the constructor that is called.

So, this statement is trying to call an `IRuntime` constructor that takes a `Destroy<IRuntime>` object as a parameter, passing a raw `IRuntime*` pointer to that parameter. No such constructor exists, so this fails to compile.

```cpp
runtime = createIRuntime();
```

`std::unique_ptr` does not have an `operator=` that takes a raw pointer, only a `std::unique_ptr`. `std::unique_ptr` has a constructor that takes a raw pointer, but that constructor is marked `explicit`. So this fails to compile, too.

```cpp
runtime = std::unique_ptr<IRuntime, Destroy<IRuntime>> (createIRuntime());
```

This is correct, and works just fine:

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/ZvhXQv)

Another statement that works is:

```cpp
runtime.reset(createIRuntime());
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/8rXzSS)

Also, since the code you showed is inside of another constructor, you can (and should) use that constructor's member initialization list:

```cpp
Test() : runtime(createIRuntime())
{
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/t0GKWM)